# How do I cancel an asynchronous operation in Silverlight/WCF?

Tags: silverlight, wcf, asynchronous

I am calling an asynchronous service from my Silverlight app and I want to be able to cancel that call after it is made. There is an option for e.Cancelled once the service has finished (i.e. If e.Cancelled Then), but how to you set that cancelled to true after you have called it? How do you cancel that asynchronous call?

Let me clarify a bit... what I am trying to do is call the SAME method twice, one right after the other, and get the results of the last call into my collection. If I call an asynchronous method twice there is no guarantee that the second call will return first, so I may end up with the results of the first call coming in last and having the wrong results in my collection. So what I would like to do is cancel the first call when I make the second so I don't get results back from the first call. Seeing as how there is a Cancelled flag in the completed event args I figure you should be able to do this. But how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's async... the transfer is passed off to a remote server and it does not return until the server is done with it.

Basically the server will keep going, but you don't have to wait for the response. Disconnect your service completed event handler and pretend it was never called. That will give the effect of cancelling the operation.

If you really need to cancel something in progress on the server you would need to make another call to the server to cancel the first call. Assuming the first call is a very slow one, this might be possible.

### Update (as question changed)

In the case you specify, it will be up to the server to cancel a operation in progress if a second one comes through, not up to the client. e.Cancelled is set server-side.

### However... :)

You have exposed a client usability issue. Shouldn't you also delay sending any service request until an idle delay has passed. That way rapid selections will not result in multiple service calls.

### Also... :>

You may also want to send a sequence number to your service calls and return that as part of the result. Then you will know if it is the latest request or not.

Comment: I'm binding a start and end date to a user control that the user can either change the start or end by dragging either end or BOTH by dragging the whole thing. Each time either the start or end change I make the call to the service. When they drag the bar and change both dates I get two sets of results, the second being the correct one... so that's why no idle delay. Maybe not the best way to do it, but...

Comment: You need to buffer the calls somewhere in between and not call a service quite so often (think of your future Azure bills! :). Currently it is like an auto-complete box calling for every keypress (they usually wait 0.5 seconds since last keystroke instead)

Comment: As mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17874542/handling-multiple-requests-for-wcf-service-in-silverlight-application I cant seem to make a another call when I have aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"...That is I have to WAIT for the first call to complate, hence I cannot call another method to signal the first method to cancel. Any help with this is appreciated.

Comment: @Allen Ho: If you have services that require `aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"` put them in a separate IIS service/site.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you really want to do is ignore the responses of all but the most recent call.

Set a unique ID (could be request #, a Guid, timestamp, or whatever) with the request, and make sure the service sends that same value back.  Keep around the ID of the most recent request and ignore response that don't match that ID.

This will be safer than cancelling the first request, since if the service has already started sending the response before the cancel request happens, you still get your error condition.

Comment: I figured out how to not have to do the calls, but that id thing sounds like a great idea, I'll have to remember that for future use. Thanks.

Comment: That's a great idea to track the most recent call Davy8, but isn't it possible to achieve this without altering the server side code, and passing the ID along the wire? I mean isn't it possible to do this by some client side trick?